# Reusing jQuery HTML Snippet to populate data from JSON Array

Tags: jquery, getelementbyid

I am trying to reuse an HTML snippet to fill an array of JSON data. The following piece of HTML is somewhere hidden (eg. css: *#empty { display: none; }* in the page. This block basically defines the HTML snippet structure of LI tags. The full contents of LI tag will work as one single row for a data in loop.

```
<ul id="empty">
    <li class="h1">
        <img class="icon" src="#link" />
        <a href="#link">NAME</a>
        <span class="count">TOTAL</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, how can I fill up the image src, href, anchor text and TOTAL value in jQuery? Beginning with the following code, how to accomplish it?

```
var item = $('#empty').clone();
// item.img.src = ??
// item.a.href == ??
// item.a.text == ??
// item.span.text = ??

$('ul#mainlist').append(item);
```

Comment: If you want to reuse HTML snippets, perhaps you may want to use mustache.js, is that an option for you? That way you define the snippet as a template, and you don't have to do the cloning manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the find function on the item variable:

```
 var item = $("#empty").clone();
 item.find("a").empty().append("new text");
 item.find("span").append(" $25.00");
 //...   
 $("div").append(item);
```

The idea is that clone() returns a jQuery object, and therefore you can use further jQuery functions on it, like find.

See example: http://plnkr.co/edit/sduJSXwyzUv44Zk8qfyK?p=preview

Comment: This one works better for my specific problem. Some improvements might be instead of empty() ones, using: item.find('a')[0].href='product.php';

Answer (score 1):

Usual approach is to create `script` tag on the page with the content of your template, ie

```
<script type='template/html' id='empty'>
  <li class="h1">
    <img class="icon" src="#link" />
    <a href="#link">[NAME]</a>
    <span class="count">[TOTAL]</span>
  </li>
</script>
```

Then you cache html of the template in variable and replace your data:

```
 var template = $('#empty').html() // cache html of the template
 var ul = $('ul.main') // cache ul where you going to insert data into

 $.ajax(...).then(function(data) {

     var html = data.myArray.map(function(e) {
         return template
                   .replace('[NAME]', e.name)
                   .replace('[TOTAL]', e.total)
                   .replace('[LINK]', e.link)
     }).join('')
     ul.html(html)
 })
```